# What is the Kotlin equivalent of Python generators?

Tags: python, kotlin, generator, sequence, yield

If I have a python generator function, let's say this one:

```py
def gen():
    x = 0
    while (true):
        yield x
        x += 1
```

This function remembers its current state, and every time you call `gen()`, yields a new value. Essentially, I would like a Kotlin sequence which can remember its state.

Comment: Perhaps: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html

Comment: Sequences are meant to be used for one-shot processing operations - if you want state you could grab an iterator, e.g. `val gen = generateSequence(-1) { it + 1 }.iterator()` and call `next()` on it

Comment: I edited (and undeleted) my answer because I found a better Kotlin equivalent to Python generators: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/iterator.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```python
> def gen():
>     x = 0
>     while (true):
>         yield x
>         x += 1
> ```
>
> This function remembers its current state, and every time you call `gen()`, yields a new value.

This is incorrect. Every time you call `gen()` you get a new "generator object" whose state is independent of any other generator object created by this function. You then query the generator object to get the next number. For example:

```python
def demo():
    numbers = gen()  # 'gen()' from your question
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        next_number = next(numbers)
        print(next_number)


if __name__ == '__main__'
    demo()
    print()
    demo()
```

Output:

```
0
1
2

0
1
2
```

As you can see, the sequence of numbers "starts over" when you call `gen()` again (though if you kept a reference to the old generator object it would continue from 2, even after calling `gen()` again).

In Kotlin, you can use the [kotlin.sequences.iterator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/iterator.html) function. It creates an `Iterator` which lazily yields the next value, just like a Python generator object. For example:

```kotlin
fun gen() = iterator {
    var x = 0
    while (true) {
        yield(x)
        x++
    }
}

fun demo() {
    val numbers = gen()
    repeat(3) {
        val nextNumber = numbers.next()
        println(nextNumber)
    }
}

fun main() {
    demo()
    println()
    demo()
}
```

Which will output:

```
0
1
2

0
1
2
```

Just like the Python code.

Note you can do the essentially the same thing with a Kotlin `Sequence`, you just have to convert the `Sequence` into an `Iterator` if you want to use it like a Python generator object. Though keep in mind that Kotlin sequences are meant more for defining a series of operations and then lazily processing a group of elements in one go (sort of like Java streams, if you're familiar with them).

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the clarification. Sorry for the mistake, I didn't verify my claims before posting. Your answer summed it up very well.

Answer (score -1):

As stated before in the comments https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html are the answer, and you don't even need an iterator. You can generate sequence using https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html

and here is a little playground witch produces similar sequence as your generator https://pl.kotl.in/LdboRzAzr

Comment: Could you include example(s) directly in your answer? They'd help to illustrate what you mean. (And there's no guarantee how long the Kotlin Playground page may be available, while StackOverflow answers are forever!)